# how to escape sql injections?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I've encountered a problem that when I using sql to query. like followings:

```
sql = "select * from chat where keywords like %key%";
```

when I execute this sql with % param this will be query all results of this table. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

You have missed ' ' SYMBOLS